# Word for saying that a sound is overwhelming another sound?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for saying that a sound is overwhelming another sound? By overwhelming, I mean that the sound is so loud that we can't hear the other sound. Is there a word for it?

Comment: Drown. _His voice was drowned by the roar of the traffic._

Comment: [Very often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drowned+by+noise%2Cdrowned+out+by+noise&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrowned%20by%20noise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrowned%20out%20by%20noise%3B%2Cc0) we include an extra preposition in *[the signal] was **drowned out** by [the noise]*.

Comment: My Canadian ears only like "drown out". To me, to "drown" a sound means holding it underwater until it's dead.

Answer (score 1):

"Drown" or "Drown out"

> His voice was drowned out by the roar of the traffic.

Comment: converting comments to cw